# grep & regex in terminal - stop at first occurence of character

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to match phrases like translatedString:@"the string"]

I have entered the following in Terminal, which works but brings back everything in the line after the match

```
grep -oh 'translatedString:.*]' ArticleV.m
```

How can I adjust the expression so that it only returns matches until the ] is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` matches greedily.  Use `.*?` (and an extended regular expression) instead:

```
grep -ohE 'translatedString:.*?]' ArticleV.m
```

If you don't like the `-E` flag, `egrep` works the same way:

```
egrep -oh 'translatedString:.*?]' ArticleV.m
```

Comment: Hi, `?` doesn't seem to work for my on GNU grep, but works with BSD grep. Any idea why?